# Sphinx HTML builder render function

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I included a `raw` directive in my `rst` file:

```
.. raw:: html

   < html here >
```

In the HTML, there is a dynamically placed string that contains reStructuredText. Since it is placed within the `raw` directive, it is not rendered as HTML, instead it remains reStructuredText.

Thus, how can I access sphinx's render function such that I can manually generate HTML as it would be produced outside the `raw` directive automatically?

I read through a couple of sphinx files, but I might lack some basic information.

My understanding is that:

- jinjia is used for template rendering but not conversion of files
- sphinx has various builders, one is the html builder (e.g. `make html`)

I tried using the pandoc interface, but pandoc produces different HTML than sphinx. So I need to access the sphinx conversion function.

It seems that docutils is used for conversion, but running it standalone produces different html as well. So I assume that sphinx uses a template which I am not aware of.

Thank you!

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you saying that you put reST syntax inside the HTML content, which in turn you expect the `raw` directive to process as reST? If so, that's not possible. Instead you can have an opening `raw` directive with HTML, then your reST, then a closing `raw` directive.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Two aspects: You say it's not possible, yes, not with normal usage of sphinx. However, it should be possible to manually process that part (with custom jinjia filters added to the environment) by calling the conversion function sphinx internally uses.

Comment: However, all that becomes unnecessary when thinking about your super simple solution — two directives. Well ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an opening `raw` directive with HTML, then your reST, then a closing `raw` directive.

```
.. raw:: html

   <html open>

Some reST stuff, oooh, a `link to the raw directive
<http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through>`_

.. raw:: html

   <html close>
```