# Sphinx alias support (substitutions ?)

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext, sections

I'm considering to move my documentation from Doxygen to Sphinx and looking for an alternative for Doxygen alias.

In Doxygen I have an alias that replaces complex command like a table to a more readable format like this (this just an examples and i have more complex and nested ones) :

```
   table_row2{2}=<tr><td align= center>\1</td><td align= center>\2</td></tr>
```

or

```
 limited_res{1}=The number of supported \1 depends on the specific platform. See the \ref appendixes section"
```

It can be used in the documentation like this:

```
...
table_h2{ Resource Name, Value }  
table_row2{ MAC Entries , 256}
table_row2{ Ingress Flow , \limited_res { Ingress Flow } }
...
```

The closest thing I found in Sphinx is substitutions, but I have trouble to get it to work even for simple command substitutions one like below:

```
.. |H1| replace:: `*****************************************************`

My section
|H1|
```

H1 either does not compile or just print the '*...*'.

I'm not sure if this is a syntax problem or just can't be done. I trying to avoid remembering which of the */ +/ -/ = means what and name it by the level of the nesting. My memory is not very good this days :)

And the more important problem:  substitutions does not seem to accept parameters which I found essential.

Another option I can think about is to write extensions like [this](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html), but I hope for a more simple method.

Answer (score 0):

To get the asterisks to appear below "My section", you need to have at least one blank line separating "My section" from "|H1|".  White space in Sphinx/docutils has meaning, and the separated content gets interpreted as two paragraphs instead of inline text.

```
.. |H1| replace:: `*****************************************************`

My section

|H1|
```

To display the backticks, escape them with the backslash character `\`.

```
.. |H1| replace:: \`*****************************************************\`

My section

|H1|
```

In case you want to insert raw, you may use the [`raw` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307708/2214933).

**EDIT**

This creates a [section](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#sections).

```
My section
==========
```

A blank line between two paragraphs will generate paragraphs, as noted above.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I don't want the asterisks to appear below "My section". I want to generate a command that creates a section or paragraph.

Comment: yes, I understand how to create a section, I'm trying to create an alias named H1 that will create it.

Comment: reStructuredText requires that the length of the underlining characters match that of the section text. Aliasing sounds needlessly complicated.

Comment: from my experience, it needs to be bigger, but anyway it's just an example of usage. I have tons of other.  Just testing how aliasing can be done on sphinx

Comment: It is not possible to use substitutions to generate section headings. Substitutions are for inline text. A heading is a two-line block consisting of the title and the underline adornment string (at least as long as the title).

Comment: So no preprocessor in the build process. The only option is to write an extension? Can I do an extension with syntax like this: ..heading:: type, title? I know it's overkill for this purpose but I'm looking for a generic way to handle different use cases I had in doxygen.